# Not found error when sending ajax data to php, but working without localhost in url

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I keep getting error 
`POST http://localhost/kipsalahome/app/views/classes/Slider.php 404 (Not Found)`
But when i remove localhost from URL link is working and data is displaying, before i sent data to other PHP script from same directory `classes` but different file and link with localhost in url bar is working perfectly.
Data is being send from selection

Here is my ajax request

```
let selected = selectLang.options[selectLang.selectedIndex].value;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'app/views/classes/Slider.php',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { param: selected },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {

            let responseText = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
            console.log(responseText.messages);
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
  <select class="form-control" id="select_language">
      <option value="en">English</option>
      <option value="ru">Russian</option>
  </select>
```

If i type in the address bar : `kipsalahome/app/views/classes/Slider.php`
the url is working

Path to project (kipsalahome)

```
C:\Users\User\Dropbox\Projects\Web\kipsalahome\
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteBase /Projects/Web/kipsalahome/public/
```

Comment: can you also show the code-version that is _not_ working?

Comment: What URL are you using in your browser to access the page that does the submit? If you omit the url from the AJAX call it will default the host to whatever host you used to open the site.

Comment: @Jeff code that i posted isn't working property file is not found

Comment: i'm not using form to submit the value, just getting vlaue form option tag and submitting it to php

Comment: Could you show your folder and file structure in your localhost? I want to see where the 'kipsalahome' directory is located. Also how do you confirm that there is a 404 error?

Comment: The `localhost` part of your URL maps to your server's htdocs / public_html folder. And if you put `http://localhost/kipsalahome/app/views/classes/Slider.php` in the browser's address bar, you should see the file. Solving a 404 error with PHP is about checking the path and making sure everything's spelled correctly, essentially. It's not more difficult than that.

Comment: yes file is found, but without http://localhost in URL bar

Comment: @Andrew Please be more specific... what exactly did you put in the address bar?

Comment: this URL `kipsalahome/app/views/classes/Slider.php`  works, this is where request is being sent: `kipsalahome/app/views/classes/Slider.php` and it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Check your network tabs in the browser. 
If the "OPTIONS" request is also failing, it can be a CORS problem.

If so, you should add some heades in your php scripts, like so:

`<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Comment: It's not an answer, post as comment please

Comment: They're getting 404, how is this CORS related? It's just PHP, there's no second server involved.